# How do I get these radio buttons to display inline?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used the code below to add a tip field to Woocommerce Checkout. The code places the radio buttons one above the other as well as the labels below the radio button. How do I get the labels to show next to the radio buttons as well as the radio buttons to display inline?

```
function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice() {

   $chosen = WC()->session->get('radio_chosen');
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? WC()->checkout->get_value('radio_choice') : $chosen;
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? 'no_option' : $chosen;

   $args = array(
   'type' => 'radio',
   'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
   'options' => array(
      'no_option' => 'None',
      'option_1' => '10%',
      'option_2' => '15%',
      'option_3' => '20%',
   ),
   'default' => $chosen
   );

   echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
   echo '<h3>Add a TIP!</h3>';
   woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
   echo '</div>';

}
```

### Update

Here is the HTML generated by the php. I did not apply any custom CSS.

```
<div id="checkout-radio">
    <h3>Add a TIP!</h3>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="radio_choice_field" data-priority="">
      <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="no_option" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_no_option">
        <label for="radio_choice_no_option" class="radio ">None</label>
        <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="option_1" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_option_1">
        <label for="radio_choice_option_1" class="radio ">10%</label>
        <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="option_2" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_option_2" checked="checked">
        <label for="radio_choice_option_2" class="radio ">15%</label>
        <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="option_3" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_option_3">
        <label for="radio_choice_option_3" class="radio ">20%</label>
      </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

### Update #2

Here is the CSS that fixed the issue:

```
#checkout-radio label.radio {
  display: inline!important;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#checkout-radio input[type=radio] {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please share the HTML this outputs as well as current CSS

Comment: Readers can't say definitively why a given question is downvoted, unless the voters themselves own up and explain. Anonymous voting is permitted here, and there is a long history of why that is unlikely to change. Perhaps in this case, there was no indication of what you had tried. Could you create a JS Fiddle or Stack Snippet containing your HTML/CSS, so readers can see the issue? I assume one would use `float: left` here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it steered me towards the answer, which I will post above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CSS that fixed the issue:

```
#checkout-radio label.radio {
  display: inline!important;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#checkout-radio input[type=radio] {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```